# Database interaction (private-public)

Tags: database, editor, private

I like to have a nice website for my client.

I will do it with WordPress. But that client will manage a database, much like Excel or Lotus or Access or FileMaker.

I like to offer the same style of database interaction (add, modify, query) with ans private access to wordpress... can i do that and how ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think about pods cms or taxonomy ? i am in the right direction ?

Comment: WordPress doesn't work with other databases.  Do you want to manage these external databases (you list several in your question)?  Or ... what?  Please clarify exactly what you're looking for ...

Comment: No i dont what to connect... i like to make wordpress look and feel as...

Comment: In that case (and this is very rare for me to say) I don't think WordPress is the right tool for that.

Comment: @EAMann You could probably design your own admin interface, etc...but why you would do that when the one they have is as good as it is is beyond me (wow...I used is a lot)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forget that kind of interaction... drupal ? IDK

Comment: Not an answer. Please, take some time to _add value_.